# CDK Syntax error being experienced in Visual Studio

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk

I am new to using AWS CDK. I have been tasked to create some simple code to deploy into AWS to create VPC, NLB, S3.

I have tried to use various editors to highlight what could be the error and yet I am still not finding the error in my ways. I would like to understand where I have gone wrong and get some tuition and and best practices going forward.

```typescript
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import { aws_ec2 as ec2, aws_s3 as s3, aws_certificatemanager as acm } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { ApplicationLoadBalancer, ApplicationProtocol, ListenerAction, ApplicationTargetGroup, TargetType } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-elasticloadbalancingv2';


export class InfrastructureStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    // Set up VPC
    const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, 'Infrastructure-vpc', {
      // cidr: '10.1.0.0/21',
      natGateways: 1,
      maxAzs: 2,
    });

    // S3 setup
    new s3.Bucket(this, 'Websites', {
      versioned: true
    });

    // Setup Loadbalancer
    interface PlatformElbProps {
      vpc: ec2.IVpc;
      certificate: acm.ICertificate,
      stackId: string
    }

    export class PlatformLoadbalancer extends Construct {
      public readonly loadBalancer: cdk.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2.ApplicationLoadBalancer;
      public readonly httpsListener: cdk.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2.ApplicationListener;

      constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: PlatformElbProps) {
        super(scope, id);

        // Create an Application Load Balancer
        this.loadBalancer = new ApplicationLoadBalancer(this, 'elb', {
          vpc: props.vpc,
          internetFacing: true,
          loadBalancerName: `${props.stackId}-loadbalancer`
        });

        // Create an HTTP listener for redirection to HTTPS
        this.loadBalancer.addListener('HTTPListener', {
          protocol: ApplicationProtocol.HTTP,
          port: 80,
          defaultAction: ListenerAction.redirect({
            port: '443',
            protocol: ApplicationProtocol.HTTPS,
            permanent: true,
          }),
        });

        // Create an HTTPS listener
        this.httpsListener = this.loadBalancer.addListener('HTTPSListener', {
          protocol: ApplicationProtocol.HTTPS,
          port: 443,
          certificates: [props.certificate]
        });

        // Add a wildcard domain routing rule to the HTTPS listener
        const deadEndTargetGroup = new ApplicationTargetGroup(this, 'dead-end', {
          vpc: this.loadBalancer.vpc,
          protocol: ApplicationProtocol.HTTP,
          targetType: TargetType.INSTANCE
        });
        this.httpsListener.addTargetGroups('dead-end', {
          targetGroups: [deadEndTargetGroup]
        });
        cdk.Tags.of(deadEndTargetGroup).add('Name', `${props.stackId}-dead-end`);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi Jason, welcome to Stack Overflow! We'd like to help you but we'll need a bit more information to give recommendations. Could you help us by sharing what code do you have as we speak and explain what are you trying to provision (End goal) with the CDK stack?

Comment: Hopefully the added code can be read by the community.......

Comment: Can you share the error message you're seeing?

Comment: You defined the interface and PlatformLoadbalancer class within the constructor of your InfrastructureStack class. Those should be separated

Comment: OK, thank you @cladazar for the feedback
Would / could you share how the syntax would like separated?

Comment: Add the actual error message to the question